# CMake compile -s -mt version of rabbitmq-c

Tags: c++, cmake, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

I run cmake in command prompt with:

```
mkdir build && cd build
.. cmake
```

But now, I have problem constructing the command to build realease static.
I tried:

```
C:\Users\Kuba\Downloads\rabbitmq-c>cmake --build  build --BUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON
```

Which yields the error:

```
Unknown argument --BUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON
```

How to correct this? Thanks !

Comment: You can also use cmake-gui to set these variables in a GUI. You may want to delete the build folder and try again. Since something was broken in your last comment. ALL_BUILD should always exist in a Visual Studio CMake generated project.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks , I will try

Answer (score 1):

You should *define* the variable using the `-D` option:

```
cmake --build  build -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON
```

Please [read the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake.1.html) for more information.

Comment: To have any effect, this would have to be specified when *generating,* not when *building.*

Comment: Now I try:
C:\Users\Kuba\Downloads\rabbitmq-c\build>cmake --build .
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the build is a separate step from building it.

From the source directory create a binary directory:

```
mkdir build && cd build
```

Then configure the build (this is where you can add other build-flags):

```
cmake -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON ..
```

then build it:

```
cmake --build .
```

Comment: @alanxyz I compile rabbit-c  in version "-s-mt" and now when I try static compile with wrapper SimpleAmqpClient i get some error when linking c library , could you help me ? I no have idea ... http://pastebin.com/DqNiaUVz

Comment: @JakubJańczak-Zarycki - SimpleAmqpClient cannot currently be built statically on Win32.

Comment: @alanxyz , future ?

Comment: @JakubJańczak-Zarycki perhaps.